# how to add extra ';'(semi colon) or any special character in all columns except first column and empty cell value from csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am using below code to add extra special character on all column except first column and empty cell value   but code isn't working yet.

```
$path = 'F:\temp.csv'

Import-Csv $path | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.value -eq $path.value ) {
        $_.value = ';'+$path.value
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Please see Image for more details:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ubu.png)

Please find csv file uploaded on Google Drive:
[CSV FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rhdj5UvM8bHDXw0RZ-dz2QCi-pNevxe4z-LWAIMV4W0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what is `$a` means?  and what is `$path.value` `$path` is just a string it has no value property, also where is `$_.Enabled` the attached csv has no Enabled property!! please edit your question and add the missing information...

Comment: @Avshalom Please help me out to the get result.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this? It looks like you are trying to create a new csv with a `;` as delimiter instead of the comma it has now. If that is your goal then `(Import-Csv $path) | Export-Csv $path Delimiter ';'  -NoTypeInformation` would do that.

Comment: @Theo , Solution has been given by Daniel.

Comment: Sure, but I still would like to know what this is for if not simply change the delimiter of the file..

Comment: @Theo, I thought that at first as well, but I think maybe Nishit is trying to build some sort of expression table where the values in the rows will be combined or something.  I don't think they are trying to change the delimiter or it would not make sense to NOT add the ';' for empty cells since that would throw off the columns in those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with $a, but if we remove that seems like you were close :)

Instead of checking if a value equals something we will just take every object and add a new property (i.e., a new column) to the object.  We will call it 'B' and make the value the same as what's in 'A' but prefix a ';' to it using `-replace`.  This replace operator uses regex so if we specify that we would like to replace '^', we are saying we would like to replace the start of the line/value.  We replace this with ';' and save as our value.  Then we output the object as you were already doing and then convert back to csv.

```
$path = 'F:\temp.csv'
Import-Csv $path | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'B' -NotePropertyValue ($_.A -replace '^', ';')
    # or instead of -replace we can do similar to how you were trying
    # $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'B' -NotePropertyValue (';' + $_.A)
    $_
} | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

***Update***
Per your comment, this code should update values in all columns except the first where value is not null/empty

```
$path = 'F:\temp.csv'
$data = Import-Csv $path 

# Track all the properties (columns) minus the first
$props = $data[0].psobject.Properties.Name | Select-Object -Skip 1

$data | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($prop in $props) {
        if ( -not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.$prop)) ){
            $_.$prop = ';' + $_.$prop
        }
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Daniel , Thanks for responding my question. I have removed $a , but this for single column but I have more 100 column then how can I manage using your code.

Comment: You want to append ';' to the beginning of every value of every column?

Comment: Daniel , Yes sir , except A 1st column and empty cell .

Comment: This is a bit different then how I interpreted your question.  So your csv is already filled in with 100 columns - colA, colB, colC, colD, etc. and each column already has values?  You want to update the existing non-null values in colB, colC, etc. to have ';' appended to the existing values already in those cells?  colA should remain untouched.

Comment: Daniel , I have update the question. There is no any column have value start with ';' semi colon , Yes I wanna update colB, colC , etc with add ';' in starting of existing value. ColA has do nothing same as earlier.